# Is it possible to create a Spring Batch job that reads and writes specific CSV columns?

Tags: java, csv, spring-batch

I have a working implementation of a user uploading a CSV, and selecting specific columns to persist in the db (these will be used for math operations/transformed later on). This same operation also creates a "dump" table using those column names.

This CSV has no specific layout or format - meaning that I do not have information about their column order or column names other than what they have specified. They will also always have a bunch of additional columns that I won't need (1000+) - which means I would only like to get the very specific columns that the user selected. The CSV, however, will always be comma-delimited and with minimal quoting mode. Obviously nothing is static here, as the selected columns and their layout will vary from CSV to CSV.

Is it possible to use the columns specified by the already created functionality and use them to read the CSV and insert them in a table? If so where do I start? And what additional information would I need (column position/index, etc)?

Comment: The only option I see for your use case is to dynamically create a `LineMapper` based on the uploaded CSV file and the selected columns.

Comment: Right but linemapper depends on a model/entity, or am i wrong? I'm just worried that I won't have any entities since they all differ from one and other.

Comment: That's not necessary. The line mapper can return a String which is a subset or superset of the raw string. Mapping data to a domain model is optional.

Comment: ok so are there any specific examples i could follow? Like i said i will have the column names available but can also probably include column positions. Since the table is already being created, i would have to insert these values in.